# Subscribing to an observable in an Angular 2 HTML element

Tags: html, angular, rxjs, observable

I have an observable producing `Users` that have an `isLoading` property, such that this yields the expected result:

```
{{ (user$ | async).isLoading }}
```

I would like to be able to use this `isLoading` property in an HTML attribute, like this:

```
<button md-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="user$.isLoading">Login</button>
```

but no syntax I use seems to do the trick. How do you subscribe to an observable like this in an HTML attribute?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use async pipe in html tag like in example below, just don't forget safe operator:

```
<button md-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="(user$ | async)?.isLoading">Login</button>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Didn't realise you could use that syntax in attributes.

Answer (score 7):

One option you have here, if you've upgraded to Angular 4, is to use `*ngIf`.  You can do something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async; let user">

{{user.isLoading}}    

<button md-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="user.isLoading">Login</button>

</div>
```

With `*ngIf` you can subscribe to the observable with `async` and assign the value to a variable with `let`.  Then user the variable in other places in your template.

This is a new feature added in Angular 4.  Most Angular2 apps can be upgraded to 4 with no changes required.

Hope that helps.