# get value of async pipe form value (observable in value attribute of input)

Tags: forms, angular, angular2-observables, angular-reactive-forms

I have text form inputs, and I want them to act as forms and also display the values set when the form is submitted. the problem is when i submit the form, and get the value for start (`form.controls.start.value`) i get an error because that value is an observable when I look at the form in the console. the error says `cannot get value of undefined`.

I have the observable `start$` which is populating my input with the current value:

```
<div class="col">
     Pool Start:
</div>
<div class="col">
     <input
           type="text"
           class="form-control"
           formControlName="start"
           [value]="start$ | async"
     >
</div>
```

it is part of a form:

```
this.dhcpForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'start': [this.start$],
            'end': [this.end$],
            'lease': [this.lease$]
});
```

and this is my submit function assigning the form values:

```
console.log(dhcpForm);
const start = dhcpForm.controls.start.value;
const end = dhcpForm.controls.end.value;
const lease = dhcpForm.controls.lease.value;
```

again to re-iterate my question, how do I render the values inside the input field after the form is submitted when the value is 'observable'?

here is the form output:
[image: form values are observables]

[here is an example of my code*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j2l9gh?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts)(*please edit this code in a separate window or fork so this version stays the same for all)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663616/subscribing-to-an-observable-in-an-angular-2-html-element)

Comment: @SurenderKherwa So i'm already using the async pipe. how do I add the safe operator to `[value]="start$ | async"` because `[value]="(start$ | async)?" doesn't work. also I dont think this addresses my issue, the values are there already, the problem is the value is an observable

Comment: Can you add a link to the code in a plunkr or something? I'm not sure I understand your situation. Typically you would use something like object?.start to safeguard in a template

Comment: when you assign value in your formbuilder you are assigning observables, you can subscribe to them first instead and then assign values to local variable and then assign those variables to your form control

Comment: @JayDeeEss sure, I could do that, I was hoping I could still use the async pipe though

Comment: @Eeks33 there is a code snippet. hm, I wonder why this got down voted.

Comment: @FussinHussin - I'm not sure why it got down voted either. I am having a hard time understanding your situation. What JayDeeEss said sounds like something I would do. I personally avoid async pipe to keep templates simpler

Comment: @Eeks33 did you take a look at the live sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the live sample, I can make it work by removing async pipe and using patchValue to set the forms. See the forked version:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipe8hd

Does this achieve the effect you're looking for? I don't think you need to do [value] or use async pipe here at all... The fork is even less code. Let me know if this is the functionality you're going for and if you'd like it to look a certain way.

Comment: that link doesnt seem to be your version... it's still returning `[object object]` when I hit submit. also, could you post an editable version when you get it working

Comment: @FussinHussin Try this link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ipe8hd

Comment: Hey @Eeks33 that works, if you'd like to post that as an answer, I have another method working with behavior subjects

Comment: @FussinHissin - Behavior subjects will work too. Anyways I updated this answer with the same correct link. Cheers