# How to hide a div if an observable is empty

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

The Project is on Angular 8.

This question may be very basic, I didnt dive deep into observables yet.

I have an observable  `isSignedIn$` that returns something when the user is signed in.
Now I want to simply hide a div with something like

```
<div *ngIf="!isSignedIn$"> content </div>
```

so that means the div is hidden when the user is not signed in/when nothing comes from the observable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subscribing to an observable in an Angular 2 HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663616/subscribing-to-an-observable-in-an-angular-2-html-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<div *ngIf="!(isSignedIn$ | async)"> content </div>
```

you need to use the async pipe

you can read more about it here: https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe